# Lake Victoria bathymetric data

Tags: data, bathymetry, africa

I am trying to find bathymetry for Lake Victoria (or portions thereof).

Any GIS format and almost any resolution will do.

As a last resort a hydrographic chart will suffice.

Comment: Try asking on http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I made my own from 10,000 data points. This is the link if interested. [bit.ly/LV_Bathy](http://bit.ly/LV_Bathy). It only took me two years to get it together after asking the question.

[image]